# References for undergraduate Classical Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, topological-field-theory

If you know of any russian text books that are available in English On Mechanics, the undergrad level please let me know. I have Kleppner and Kolenkow but I wish to read from a Russian Author

Comment: Repost of [this closed question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732642/book-suggestions).

Comment: Why do you consider quantum mechanics and topological field theory to be undergrad-level classical mechanics?

Comment: Please do not open the very same question again. Instead, edit and try to reopen the original question.